# Arranging strings names of teams in order of points obtained by team

Tags: c

I have this project where I am supposed to write a code whereby we enter the names of the country competing in the world cup (1 group, 4 countries) and what each country scored. Then, the program has to print the scores and which two teams are to advance to the next stage like "1st team to advance is %s." and it prints the name of the team with the highest score followed by "2nd team to advance is %s." , printing the country with the 2nd highest score. I can't for the life of me figure out how to write the part where the program prints which country advances to the next stage.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

#define NUMBER 4 

void setTeam(char team[NUMBER][20]) /*Names of team in particular group*/
{ 

 setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0); 

 int i;
 for(i=0;i<NUMBER;i++){ 
  printf("Enter name of team %d: ", i); 
  scanf("%s", &team[i]); 
 } 

 for(i=0;i<NUMBER;i++){  /*print name of teams entered*/
      printf("team[%d]=\" %s\"\n", i, team[i]); 
 } 
} 

void input(char team[NUMBER][20],int group[NUMBER][7]){  /*Enter goals scored 
to calculate Wins, Draws, Loss, GF, GA, GD and PTS */

  int score_i, score_j;
  int i, j; 
  for(i=0;i<NUMBER-1;i++){ 
      for(j=i+1;j<NUMBER;j++){ 
          printf("%s vs %s\n",team[i],team[j]); 

          printf("%s :",team[i]); scanf("%d", &score_i); 

          group[i][3] += score_i;

          printf("%s :",team[j]); scanf("%d", &score_j); 

          group[j][3] += score_j;

          group[i][4] += score_j;
          group[j][4] += score_i;

          if (score_i == score_j)
          {
                group[i][1] += 1;
                group[j][1] += 1;
          } else if (score_i > score_j) {
               group[i][0] += 1;
               group[j][2] += 1;
          } else {
               group[j][0] += 1;
               group[i][2] += 1;
          }

          group[i][5] += judge(score_i, score_j);
          group[j][5] += judge(score_j, score_i);
          group[i][6] = group[i][3] - group[i][4];
          group[j][6] = group[j][3] - group[j][4];
      } 
  }
} 

int judge(int gain, int loss)
{

   if (gain == loss || loss == gain)
        return 1;
   else if (gain > loss)
        return 3;
   else
       return 0;
 } 

int display(char team[NUMBER][20], int group[NUMBER][7])
{ /*Print results*/

  puts("\n\tTeam, \t\tWin,    Draws,   Loss,    GF,    GA,     GD,    PTS");  

  int i, j;  

  for(i=0;i < NUMBER;i++){  

      printf("\t%-10s,\t%3d,\t%8d,\t%d,\t%2d,\t%3d,\t%5d,\t%9d\n", 
      team[i],group[i][0],group[i][1],group[i][2],group[i][3],group[i] 
      [4],group[i][5],group[i][6]); 
  } 
  putchar('\n');
} 

void advance(char team[][20], int group[][7])
{ /*Identify top 2 teams to advance and print name of teams */

  int i, j;
  int max;
  char temp[NUMBER][20];

  puts("\tAdvance");

  for(i = 0; i < NUMBER; i++) {
        for(j = i + 1; j < NUMBER; j++) {
                if (group[i][3] < group[j][3]) {
                     max = group[i][3];
                     group[i][3] = group[j][3];
                     group[j][3] = max;

                 }
        }
   }


}



int main(void)
{ 

 int group[NUMBER][7] = {0}; 
 int i,j; 
 char team[NUMBER][20]; 

 setTeam(team); 
 input(team, group); 
 display(team, group); 
 advance(team, group);

 return 0; 
}
```

Comment: When looking at a group of 4 teams, using qsort() might be a bit overkill. 3 manual comparisons should suffice (or maybe up to 5 in the worst case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compare teams by amount of points earned. I initialized state by assigning that the first and the second team are candidates for next stage. After that all you have to do is to compare whether there is some other team with higher score. If you have found new highest score you need to reassign both first and second team. If you have found a new 2nd place candidate you need to reassign only the second place.

```
void advance(char team[][20], int group[][7])
{ /*Identify top 2 teams to advance and print name of teams */

  int i, j;
  int max;

  int max_id = 0;
  int max_id_prev = 1;

  puts("\tAdvance");

  for(i = 1; i < NUMBER; i++) {
    if (group[max_id][5] < group[i][5]) {
       max_id_prev = max_id;
       max_id = i;
       continue;
    }
    if (group[max_id_prev][5] < group[i][5]) {
       max_id_prev = i;
    }
   }
  printf("%s", team[max_id]);
  printf("%s", team[max_id_prev]);
}
```

Please consider doing a peer review of your code or post your code on [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Also consider organizing your code with structs as representations of the data you have. It will improve readability. There are many books on how to write clean, readable code.

Comment: I'm actually a total beginner and at my university, we begin learning with C language. I'm always looking to improve myself. Thank you for your suggestions. If you don't mind, could you please tell me what structs are? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a great book, frequently mentioned here, called The C Programming Language (sometimes called K&R) from Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie.  You can find a lot of information there about C (including structs).